# How to bring on ScatterViewItem in a collection of ScatterViewItem to the foreground?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I have a lot of ScatterViewItems that I programatically add to a ScatterView. Now I have also a DropDown list. Every time I choose an item in the DropDown list, I'd like to change the background of the corresponding ScatterViewItem, and if multiple ScatterViewItems are overlapping, I'd like to bring the corresponding ScatterViewItem in the foreground.

Changing the background color is no problem. But how can I bring a ScatterViewItem to the Foreground? I already tried to remove it from the ItemCollection of the ScatterView and then adding it again, so that it is the latest added ScatterViewItem. This works, but isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsActive property on the ScatterviewItem will do this job for you

Comment: Thanks, I think this should solve the problem. One question remaing, which I couldn't really find out while trying... Is it necessary to set IsActive to false for all other ScatterViewItems or is is enough if i set the focused element to true?

Comment: Yes you can keep setting IsActive to true for the SVI you are interested in. No need to set it back to false.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse "activation" for zorder.  Activation of an SVI will change it's zorder but it also does other things (like trigger animations).  If all you want to do is change the zorder of an item, use this API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.scatterviewitem.setrelativezindex(v=Surface.10).aspx